# Colocar JPanel uno al lado del otro sin espacio de separación

Tags: java, java-swing

Hola podrían ayudarme con lo siguiente ejercicio. Necesito colocar dos JPanels uno al lado del otro usando la paleta gráfica de Netbeans. Quiero hacer un gráfico de barras usando jpanels, pero no puedo dibujarlos uno al lado del otro. Cuando intento colocarlos uno al lado del otro siempre me queda una separación. Use GridLayout pero las barras quedan separadas de los ejes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que debes realizarlo así? lo menos que se utiliza es Graphics2D mira este ejemplo del sitio en inglés https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518496/drawing-a-graphical-histogram/12520104#12520104 si cambias el valor de la linea 34 a 5 obtienes las 5 lineas verticales

Comment: Y podrías mirar esto también youtube.com/watch?v=4ijB9BAFuIw es un video de ejemplo para utilizar jFreeChart, esto es mucho mejor pero lleva mucho más tiempo

Answer (score 2):

Espero que no sea demasiado tarde para responder...

> usando la paleta gráfica de Netbeans.

Supongo que te refieres al constructor gráfico de Netbeans. El comportamiento de los **jPanel** al dejar los espacios es totalmente normal si no has colocado ningún **LayoutManager**, y lo has dejado en "***Free Design***"

[image: ejemplo 1]

Estos espacios que quedan entre los componentes, se conocen como "***gap***" (brechas o espacio)

[image: ejemplo 2]

El diseñador gráfico ofrece tres tipos de valores por defecto: "*large*", "*medium*" y "*small*". Si intentas hacerlo más pequeño, el espacio no pasará de "*small*", sin embargo, **SÍ** es posible eliminar ese espacio, para eso, le das *clic izquierdo* sobre ese espacio y se abre un menú contextual:

[image: ejemplo 3]

Eliges la opción **Edit Layout Space...**. Y seguidamente borras lo que esté en "**Defined Size:**" y escribes un **0**.

[image: ejemplo 4]

Le das "**Ok**" y verás como se eliminará ese espacio entre los componentes:

[image: ejemplo 5]